# Conditionally Send WooCommerce Emails based on filter

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce-email

I have a request from a client to conditionally send an admin email from woocommerce based on some conditions.  She's using the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin and would only like to have an admin email sent to customers that are paying for a subscription (she grants subscriptions to clients manually that pay for other services).

After looking through the source for Wordpress `wp_mail`, WooCommerce `WC_Email_New_Order` class, and WooCommerce Subscriptions `WCS_Email_New_Renewal_Order` I can't find any explicit filters/actions available for me to hook into that would affect the sending of the email.

Is there a way, either within default Wordpress, default woocommerce, or default woocommerce-subscriptions to catch those emails and cancel the `wp_mail` if, in my case only, the order amount is $0.00?

I don't want to modify core plugin/Wordpress files for this.

Comment: So you would like to intercept order emails?

Comment: [This](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152546/woocommerce-new-customer-email-hook) and [this](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/unhookremove-woocommerce-emails/) may help

Comment: Thank you for your time with this. I think a combination of those may work for this solution.

Comment: I would maybe consider looking into adding a hook for woocommerce_email_before_order_table